# Does using Nvidia's Dynamic Super Resolution (DSR) at 4k more demanding on the GPU than using 4k native resolution?

Tags: windows, 4k-resolution, nvidia-dsr

I can either use a 4k monitor, or use a 1080 or 1440p monitor with Nvidia's Dynamic Super Resolution (DSR) at 4k. Which option is more demanding on the GPU/CPU, if any? In other words, will using DSR decrease the frame rate compared to using native resolution at the same resolution? I'm guessing that DSR is more demanding but I have no idea whether it is x1.01  or x2 more demanding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to several [Reddit comments](https://redd.it/10t2ezf), using Nvidia's Dynamic Super Resolution (DSR) at 4k has the virtually same GPU computational cost as using 4k native resolution.